# Seaborn heatmap annotation not centered

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a very simple seaborn heatmap:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df_cm = pd.read_csv('test_cm.csv',index_col=0)
sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

This is different from the expected behavior where (1) annotations are in the center of the box and (2) the y axis labels are also centered and vertical.

My `seaborn` version is `0.9.0` and `matplotlib` version is `3.1.1`.

I'm confused what's the difference between the script above and numerous other seaborn heatmap tutorials that use the same code but have the texts aligned beautifully.